# Accessing the Selected property on TitleBar tabs

Tags: titlebar, xpages

I am using the Application Layout control and have tabs in the TitleBar.  I want to change the style of the tab if it is selected.  I am currently doing it by comparing the value of the tab to a sessionScope variable I am setting when the tab is clicked.

I saw something (though I can't find it now) about using the Selected property of the Basic Node I am using for the tab.  How would I access that in SSJS so that I can do something like this?

```
if(thisnode.selected) {
    return "lotusTabs liActive";
} else {
    return "lotusTabs li";
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS rule will target the selected title tab:

```
div.lotusTitleBar ul.lotusTabs li.lotusSelected {
// your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I finally figured out the CSS piece, though I may go back and rethink my solution in light of your answer. I'm still curious if there is a way to access that property through JavaScript.

Comment: Just thought of this too: does that CSS translate to "Apply this style to an LI with the class of lotusSelected if its UL has the class lotusTabs and the UL is in a DIV with the class lotusTitleBar"? And if you left off the DIV, then it would apply to any element using lotusTitleBar?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also access the tabs programmatically:

```
var layout = getComponent("layoutId");
var selectedTab = null;
var tabs = layout.getConfiguration().getTitleBarTabs();
for (var tab in tabs) {
  if (tab.getSelected()) {
    selectedTab = tab;
  }
}
```